# bash split a variable into two or more based on character length

Tags: bash

I built a script for SMS autoresponder, my goal is that when an sms content has more than 160 of character length, it splits the content into two or more variables then send them separately.

```
myvar="this variable has more than ten character length"
```

That variable has 48 of character length, how do I print that variable from length 1 to length 25 and length 26 to 48 ? So i'll have 2 variables in the end and send those variables with sms:

```
firstvar="this variable has more th"
secondvar="an ten character length"
```

I know there's a command `split` but my openwrt doesn't support that command, so I have to find another way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this snippet should help you:

```
myvar="this variable has more than ten character length"
size=${#myvar} 
if [ $size -gt 25 ]; then
    firstvar=${myvar:0:25}
    secondvar=${myvar:26:size}
    echo "$firstvar"
    echo "$secondvar"
fi
```

Comment: You should put your variable interpolations inside double quotes unless you specifically want the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wikdcard expansion on the strings.

Comment: @tripleee: where do you see word splitting and pathname expansion here?

Answer (score 1):

Bash can split a variable into substrings using it's substitution rules.

```
echo ${variable:4:8}
```

Will display eight characters starting at offset four. The offset starts at zero.

In general: 
    ${parameter:offset:length}

Answer (score 0):

A pure Bash possibility, no external tools (hence only depends on Bash and no other specific third-party tools) and no subshells:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysms="this variable has more than ten character length"
maxlength=25

sms_tmp=$mysms
sms_ary=()
while [[ $sms_tmp ]]; do
    sms_ary+=( "${sms_tmp::maxlength}" )
    sms_tmp=${sms_tmp:maxlength}
done

# At this point, you have your sms split in the array sms_ary:

# You can print them, one per line:
printf '%s\n' "${sms_ary[@]}"

# You can print them, one per line, with header:
printf -- '--START SMS-- %s --END SMS--\n' "${sms_ary[@]}"

# You can print them, space padded (spaces on the right):
printf -- "--START SMS-- %-$(maxlength}s --END SMS--\n" "${sms_ary[@]}"

# You can print them, space padded (spaces on the left):
printf -- "--START SMS-- %${maxlength}s --END SMS--\n" "${sms_ary[@]}"

# You can loop through them:
for sms in "${sms_ary[@]}"; do
    printf 'Doing stuff with SMS: %s\n' "$sms"
done

# You can loop through them with index (C-style loop):
for ((i=0;i<${#sms_ary[@]};++i)); do
    printf 'This is SMS #%d at index %d: %s\n' "$((i+1))" "$i" "${sms_ary[i]}"
done

# You can loop through them (using array key as variable):
n=1
for i in "${!sms_ary[@]}"; do
    printf 'This is SMS #%d at index %d: %s\n' "$((n++))" "$i" "${sms_ary[i]}"
done

# Here's the number of SMS:
printf 'That was fun. There were %d chunks of SMS\n' "${#sms_ary[@]}"
```

---

Another way to split your string:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysms="this variable has more than ten character length"
maxlength=25

sms_ary=()
for ((i=0;i<${#mysms};i+=maxlength)); do
    sms_ary+=( "${mysms:i:maxlength}" )
done

# Same as before, at this point you have your chunks in array sms_ary
```

Comment: This is quite useful with example and different approaches. Why down vote it?